# Query with the postgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier, string-constant

I already have a database created by postgresql (provided by another administrator than me), the command is created as shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE "Districts" (
    "Name" character varying(500),
    "ProvinceCode" text
);
```

The query Insert value to my table as follows:

```
Insert into Districts (Name,ProvinceCode) values ("Abc","Xyz"); `ERROR:  relation "districts" does not exist`
```

I have also tried:

```
Insert into "Districts" (Name,ProvinceCode) values ("Abc","Xyz"); `ERROR:  column "name" of relation "Districts" does not exist`
```

And:

```
Insert into "Districts" ("Name","ProvinceCode") values ("Abc","Xyz"); `ERROR:  column "Abc" does not exist`
```

I do not know how the syntax is correct. I really need someone to help.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: never use double quotes (`"`)  in SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote identifiers, you use `"` (double quotes). (Unquoted characters will also be interpreted as identifiers, just ignoring the case (converted to lower case) and splitting at whitespace.)

Quotes around a string literal are `'` (single quotes). At least this is part of the SQL Standard.

Thus the correct insert for you is:

```sql
INSERT INTO "Districts" ("Name", "ProvinceCode") VALUES ('Abc', 'Xyz');
```

Anyways, I would usually not recommend using quoted identifiers (because you always need to carry them around with usually no real gain). Thus, if possible, I would recommend renaming the table and its columns to `districts, name, province_code` (but since this is in some sense not your table, it might be too late for this). After this, your insert would look like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO districts (name, province_code) VALUES ('Abc', 'Xyz');
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for the answer.